# Using Three20 ThumbViewer with AssetsLibrary framework

Tags: ios, ios4, three20, assetslibrary

I'm trying to use `TTThumbsViewController` in conjunction with the `AssetsLibrary` framework to present a photo gallery similar to the one built into the iPhone.

I'm trying by implementing a Photo class which implementes `NSObject<TTPhoto>` and wrapping the appropriate properties, but getting hung up on size, which is supposed to be a `CGSize`.

#### Short question:

How do I find the dimensions of an `ALAsset` as a `CGSize`?

#### Long question:

Am I going down the right road? Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the Three20 project, while excellent adds a lot of overhead to your project.
If you just want a better ImagePicker, you might take a look at this project:

https://github.com/guicocoa/photopicker-ios#readme

Cheers,

Hendrik